# Manipulating the black and white pixels in Android bitmap

Tags: android, android-studio, bitmap, android-bitmap, android-graphics

I am developing an app for clicked an image and convert the bitmap to binary. Here is some of my code of converting the image to binary:

```
    File file = new  File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Watershed/WatershedImages", "Image_"+Save.MyDate+".jpg");
    Mat origianlImage = Imgcodecs.imread(file.getAbsolutePath());
    Mat image1Mat = new Mat();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(origianlImage,image1Mat, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);
    Mat mat3 = new Mat();
    Core.inRange(image1Mat, new Scalar(0, 0, 0), new Scalar(50, 255, 255), mat3);
    Mat mat4 = new Mat();    
    Imgproc.threshold(mat3, mat4, 0, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
    Bitmap threshBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mat4.cols(), mat4.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(mat4, threshBitmap);
```

The image is converted to bitmap. I have checked the color of pixels and found out that black pixel value is -16777216 and white is -1. For further processing, I need to change these values to original java type (0 for black and 255 for white).

How to manipulate the pixel values from -16777216 to 0 and -1 to 255 WITHOUT changing the colors? Is there any way? Please help.

Comment: `black pixel value is -16777216`. That is not the way to display a color. Please write the values in hexadecimal notation first.

Comment: sorry I didn't get you. Can you please explain in detail? How to change it from -16777216 to 0?

Comment: Well google for how to print the value of an integer hexadecimal. And further google for color representations. Ever heard of RGB?

Comment: Ya. I have also printed the corresponding RGB values. For black pixel, they are 0 and for white pixel they are 255,255,255

Comment: That is decimal. Normally one gives color values hexadecimal. So please try again. If you dont try you never will know what `-1` actually is in rgb.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. What should I try? Printing the values of Red Green and Blue for the corresponding Black and white pixels?? I just want to change the pixel values of Black from -16777216 to 0 and white pixels from -1 to 255. How to do this?

Comment: `What should I try?`. That i already told you. Hexadecimal notation. If you want to manipulate colors you have to know what you do. You again posted a big negative integer. Terrible.